# Makefile and Bash script for C++ with command line arguments

Tags: c++, linux, bash, unix, makefile

For my homework, I just wrote a c++ program that should supply a command line argument(e.g. `-l`) when you run it. Now, I need to compile and run my program in Unix. So, I need a makefile and a bash script(the name is `cddb`) to invoke my program.

My question is that the sequence of two files. The requirement is like I should enter `cddb -l` to run the program. So, is it like I should write a bash script which invokes the makefile and pass the argument to makefile. Then the makefile taken the argument and compile and run my cpp file?

Comment: The makefile tells `make` how to build your program, that's it. Then you simply run your program like any other command or program. E.g. if your program executable is in the current directory, you do `./cddb -l`. No shell script needed.

Comment: I don't see why you need a bash script. Just do everything in the makefile (have a target `run:` or so).

Comment: I don't see why you need either a makefile or a bash script. Homework programs are rarely complex enough to need a makefile, and you don't need a bash script just to run a program.

Comment: It sounds like you need *either* a bash script *or* a Makefile to build your program. Beginners often put the compile commands into a bash script and later learn how to build Makefiles. Just put whatever command you use to build your program into a text file called something like "build.sh" and make it executable (`chmod u+x build.sh`), then use that to build your program. `./build.sh`

Comment: Or build and execute; `g++ cddb.cpp -o cddb; ./cddb -l`.  If you like, it's obviously not hard to write a `Makefile` which contains the same commands, but if you always want to run them in sequence, having this in your Bash history is really all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of command line arguments is to change the behaviour of your executable file at run time, so you don't need to re-compile your source code if you want slightly different behaviour.

Just call your program like `./cddb -l` and parse the command line arguments in your source code. To parse the arguments you can use the **argv** and **argc** variables declared in the main function signature.